# What account do I use to log in to a Minecraft PE server?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

What account do I use to log in to a Minecraft Pocket Edition server? I have tried searching for an answer on the internet but I can't find out what account I need to use.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an account to log into an external server.

Answer (score 0):

Use your Mojang account that you use for the Mac/Linux/PC version of Minecraft.